# How the rotate command works specifically? Especially in "for" loop

Tags: asymptote

I tried to draw a disgram that contains several parallel lines in horizontal. For convenience, I use the **rotate** command to modify the lines' direction. I have tried this

```c
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(3cm);

path[] test(real begin){
    path[] res;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i){
        res.push(rotate(225)*((begin+(i-1),0)--(begin+i-0.5,0)));
    }

    return res;
}

draw(test(0));
```

However, the works of my code is this

[image]

It looks like that the rotates take place after the loop.

Where is the problem in my code? Or is there something different in rotate or for loop when compiling? I want the code packaged in a function, it's very nice of you if you could help me and give me an instance to get what I expect.

Comment: `transform rotate(real angle, pair z=(0,0));` *rotates by angle in degrees about z;*. Your `rotate(225)*` is the same as `rotate(225,(0,0))*`. What is your **z**?

Comment: Adding a degree works. Thanks.